# Как взять строку после слова и варьирующихся символов?

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения, node.js

вопрос по регуляркам JS.

Мне нужно в тексте найти все строки, начинающиеся на определенное слово (регистр не учитывается) и после него либо пробел, либо двоеточие, либо пробел+двоеточие+пробел, либо пробел+двоеточие, либо двоеточие+пробел, либо несколько пробелов. Все варианты пробела и двоеточия, в общем.

Пример нужных строк со словом word:

```
word : text text 

Word:text text 

word   text text

word: text text
```

и т.д.
То, что придумал:

```
const main_pattern = /word(( :)|(: )|( +)|( : )).*/gi;
```

Выглядит не очень :) Заранее благодарю.

Comment: Почему ваша регулярка начинается с `\/\/`?  В примерах нет `//`.

Comment: Не убрал, это часть нужного шаблона (поиск по комментариям). Правильно: const main_pattern = /word(( :)|(: )|( +)|( : )).*/gi;

Comment: Если пробел и запятая, то подходит?

Comment: @Эникейщик, в моем случае нет.

Comment: Тогда принятый ответ, насколько я понимаю, вам не подходит.

Comment: @Эникейщик, подходит. Мне нужны все строки, начинающиеся со слова word и вариаций пробела и двоеточия, так что, если находится строка "word ,", то она тоже годится, так как начинается со слова word и пробела.

Comment: Вы ж только что сказали, пробел и запятая не подходит.

Comment: @Эникейщик, неправильно понял Вас. Имелось в виду, что такая комбинация не ищется, но подходит.

Comment: Ок  (........)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я думаю, что вам нужно проверять только на первый пробел или двоеточие

```js
const reg = /word( |:).*/gi;
console.log('word : text text'.match(reg));

console.log('Word:text text'.match(reg));

console.log('word   text text'.match(reg));

console.log('word: text text'.match(reg));
```

Comment: Нужен регистронезависимый поиск, поэтому первую строку нужно поменять, добавив флаг i: const reg = /(word( |:).*/gi;